# Why is Apache giving me Server Error 500 instead of PHP errors, previously working fine?

Tags: php, apache, mamp

I've been trucking along for the past 4 weeks with my MAMP server updated and running well. Been coding PHP files, and when I make a mistake or don't understand what I'm doing, I get a nice little PHP error on the page in place of the called file.

It's helping me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Today, I sit down to start working, and suddenly I'm getting `Server Error 500`. It took me 45 minutes to track down the misspelled declaration! Why am I suddenly not getting PHP errors??

Nothing has changed that I know of. I haven't updated any apps in over a week. The PHP error log is showing the T-String errors no problem. Apache log shows absolutely nothing.

Again, as far as I know, ***no configuration has changed.***

```
MAMP ver. 3.5
Apache ver. 2.4.16 (Unix)
PHP ver. 5.6.10
```

php_error.log:

```
[26-Jan-2016 03:59:26 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/includes/pages.php on line 43
```

error reporting declaration (hasn't changed!)

```
error_reporting( E_CORE_ERROR | E_CORE_WARNING | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_USER_ERROR | E_USER_WARNING | E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR );
```

Comment: theres a syntax error on line 43 in `/includes/pages.php`. please post `pages.php` or check for syntax errors. error 500 is a generic server error code.

Comment: The error was a simple missing semicolon line terminator : `$current_page = new Page("add-new-page")` changed to `$current_page = new Page("add-new-page");`. The syntax error isn't my problem. It's the fact that I'm not getting PHP errors when I have a syntax error, like I always have.

Comment: ahh apologies, just reread your question

Comment: No problem, thanks for offering help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your php.ini file to check whether your error reporting has turn off. If this is the case then enable run time error-reporting by adding this two line in the top of your file

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

You should only do this for debugging purpose and don't forget to remove this in production server.

Comment: This caused it to display the PHP error. If I shouldn't keep these lines in during production, what setting is normally turned on that would display them. More importantly, why would it have turned out without me changing anything?

Comment: in your php.ini file search for this two line "error_reporting = "  and "display_errors = ". Here you can specify which errors should be displayed and which are not? In production server by default it should be turned off for security reason.

Comment: Cool thanks a bunch for your help. I'm still baffled as to how this got changed on it's own, but oh well!